# javascript check if class exists if so replace with same class

Tags: javascript

yup pretty much what is in the title i have this script ....

```
$('.iconM-work').on('click', function () {
     $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBig"); 
      $("#colorscreen").css('background-color', 'rgba(164, 196, 0, 0.2)');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");


});
```

but i need to add in a bit of code that says if the class fadeInUpBig already exists then do the following before changing the background color (2nd part of the script above)....

```
$(".fadeInUpBig").replaceWith($(".fadeInUpBig").clone());
```

any advice here would be very helpful.

Comment: `if` statement with `.hasClass` [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Comment: `$("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBig").css('background...', '...').relaceWith(...)` should do that.

Comment: any ideas on syntax , the documentation is difficult to interpret .... because i am an idiot and not because of the documentation itself

Comment: so would that essentially check if the class fadeinupbig exists and if so clone it or reload it or whatever replace with same class you get the idea ?

Comment: Here you go: `if ($(...).hasClass(...)) { $(...).replaceWith(...); }`. If you are unfamiliar with the syntax of an `if` statement, I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#if...else_statement, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: so like so ... if ($("#colorscreen").hasClass("fadeInUpBig")) { $("fadeInUpBig").replaceWith("fadeInUpBig"); }

Comment: also , what about the else bit of things to default to .addclass as per the 3rd line of the initial script ? or do i just simply paste it in above it ?

Comment: @user3504751: `$("fadeInUpBig").replaceWith("fadeInUpBig");` would try to replace an element with **tag name** `fadeInUpBig` (i.e. `<fadeInUpBig>`, which doesn't exist in HTML) with the **text** `fadeInUpBig`. I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial to get a basic understanding of selectors: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: so basically it's not going to work the way initially suggested , as for the how to do javascript in 5 seconds ref guide (thanks for that) i appreciate that all that would be needed after the suggested statement would be an else with braces in the corect places

Comment: I should probably mention that fadeInUpBig is a class that I am trying to replace if it already exists with the same class as jquery doesn't like the simpler term .reloadclass

Comment: Is $("#colorscreen") name of button? $(this) will point to clicked button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below

```
if ($('.colorscreen').hasClass('fadeInUpBig')) {
  $(".fadeInUpBig").replaceWith($(".fadeInUpBig").clone());
}
```

Comment: ah thanks i just did if ($("#colorscreen").hasClass("fadeInUpBig")) { $("fadeInUpBig").replaceWith("fadeInUpBig"); }  what do you think ?

Comment: $("fadeInUpBig") should be$(".fadeInUpBig")

Comment: try $( this ).removeClass( "fadeInUpBig" ).addClass( "fadeInUpBig" );

Comment: also didn't work it just skipped over as if the class was already present

Comment: .... my script now being like this $('.iconM-testimonials').on('click', function () {
     $("#colorscreen").removeClass("fadeInUpBig").addClass("fadeInUpBig");
      $("#colorscreen").css('background-color', 'rgba(164, 196, 0, 0.2)');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");

   
});